# get selected item on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Sorry about this answer, i found a lot of results but anything works on my code.

I want to get the selected item and call another function to work with this. The script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input#autoText").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "UserControllerServlet?action=Autocompletar",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: request,
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log(data);
                            var items = data;
                            response(items);
                            alert($("#autoText").val(ui.item.id));

                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(textStatus);
                        }

                    });
                }

            });
        });


    </script>
```

The alert not works, and i try to use select and nothing.

Thx.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not descriptive. Do you mean the alert doesn't trigger, or it shows empty? Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select - source is used to set the "keywords" for autocomplete or the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#autoText").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "UserControllerServlet?action=Autocompletar",
                dataType: "json",
                data: request,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var items = data;
                    response(items);
                    alert($("#autoText").val(ui.item.id));

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                }

            });
        },
        select: function (e, ui) {
            console.log('s', ui.item);
            //here ui.item will refer to the selected object
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FTZJ3/)

Comment: It's normal if i try to show the item the alert print "Object object" ? Not print the String, I want the String.

Comment: @user3157778 use `ui.item.id` or `ui.item.text` may be

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
alert($("#autoText").val(ui.item.id));
```

use

```
$("#autoText").data("autocomplete").selectedItem
```

This will allow you to access the selected item as an object.